# How to modify the NetSuite Integrated label

Tags: netsuite

I had setup the Endicia label sever in NetSuite, but I'd like to do some modify on the label.

I was customizing the NetSuite Standard Shipping Label PDF/HTML Template and marked it as PREFERRED, but it doesn't affect to the label. The information on label still incorrect.

Does anyone know how to find out the correct label template in NetSuite or who has similar issue, how do you solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: FYI who has similar issue. I was talking with NetSuite tech support. The template for integrated label was coded on the end that can't be customized.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change which shipping label is printed you need to Edit the Shipping Label Transaction Form. You can navigate there by going to Customization>Forms>Transaction Forms. Customize the Shipping Label form, select the Printint Type (in your case it sounds like it would be Basic), and then in the PDF Layout Dropdown menu, select the Shipping Label PDF you customized. Make sure this customized Transaction Form is marked Preferred, as only the Preferred shipping label prints from the Item Fulfillment record.